# Using PHP in XAMPP: can create db but cannot create tables

Tags: php, xampp

I'm a beginner programmer, and I've installed XAMPP with the intention of learning a bit of PHP. I have a working knowledge of SQL.

I've been following the PHP tutorial at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/). The problem I am currently having is this: I'm using the script [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create.asp) to create a database and a table within it. What I'm using is almost verbatim, except I've replaced the user with "root" and I've deleted the password.

After running the script through the browser, the database my_db appears in the datafile for mysql in XAMPP.

However, there is no sign of a table, and when I try to select the table, I get

> Table 'my_db.persons' doesn't exist

What is going on? Is there something wrong with the code I took verbatim, or is it something with permissions?

It's weird that the database is created but not a table...

Comment: Do Not use w3schools; http://w3fools.com/ - Naughty Developer.

Comment: XAMPP comes with something called PHPmyAdmin. It is a user interface that will let you actually look at your tables. You can visit it at this url: http://localhost/phpmyadmin   Do you see the table anywhere in those databases?

Comment: for starters put `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` before any other PHP code

Comment: @DarylGill Thanks for the link! I will try out some other tutorials. Knowing nothing about w3schools, I just picked it up off the top of the pile. Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has happenned is that your "CREATE TABLE" will have failed.

Get into the habit of checking for errors after EVERY mySQL query (in your code): there are some times you can ignore errors, but it's rare. So program alonghte lines of:

```
Create query: $sql =
Set parameters: $aParams =   (or bind paramters)
Execute query
If errors
    If debug: Show error and query
    If live: Log error and query
```

I'm not giving the solution is code, as one problem with the tutorial you follow is that it uses mysql_() functions that are going to be depreciated shortly. You should use [PDO (PHP Database Objects)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions otherwise your code will not work in a few releases time.

With PDO, you can set error handling to use exceptions, and you wrap every call in try {} catch {} and this makes the habit of catching and reporting errors very easy.

```
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE....';
    $aParams = array(
        ':param_name' => $param_value,
        ':param_name2' => $param_value2
           );

    try {
        $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmnt->execute($aParams);
        $stmnt = null;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Error log here; $e contins line of error and the actual error, you have $sql and $aParams
        LogDBError($e, $sql, $aParams);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice. I can't wait for spare time to employ it :)